# Avoid Duplicate Stripos() PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just use HTML Simple Parser to find news by typing words and got an issue on `stripos()` my result got duplicated because i type keywords **"Joe Antam"**.

Here my codes:

```
 $data['inputcari'] = $this->input->post('inputcari');

 $html = file_get_html('https://www.suara.com/bisnis/bisnis-category/keuangan');

 $data['konten'] = $html->find('div[class="item-content item-right"]');
 $data['terms'] = explode(' ', $data['inputcari']);
 foreach ($data['konten'] as $kon) {
        foreach ($data['terms'] as $term) {
            foreach ($kon->find('h4') as $h4) {
                if (stripos($h4->plaintext, $term) !== false) {
                    echo $h4->plaintext . '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it's make them display all results contain **joe** and then **antam** so the results make it twice, like this below:

> Joe Biden Jadi Presiden AS, Apa Pengaruhnya ke Indonesia 
> ****Joe** Biden Kamala Harris Dilantik, Harga Emas Antam Naik Jadi Rp 963.000 
>
> Joe Biden Kamala Harris Dilantik, Harga Emas **Antam** Naik Jadi Rp 963.000** 
>
> Nilai Tukar Rupiah Menguat Usai Joe Biden Dilantik Jadi Presiden AS 
> Pelantikan Joe Biden Kamala Harris Berimbas Positif ke IHSG 
> Joe Biden Dilantik Jadi Presiden AS, Harga Emas Dunia Makin Berkilau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `echo`ing out each line as you find it, adding them to an array and then at the end of the loop using `array_unique()` to remove the duplicates before outputting them...

```
$lines = [];
foreach ($data['konten'] as $kon) {
    foreach ($data['terms'] as $term) {
        foreach ($kon->find('h4') as $h4) {
            if (stripos($h4->plaintext, $term) !== false) {
                $lines[] = $h4->plaintext;
            }
        }
    }
}
$lines = array_unique($lines);
echo implode('<br>', $lines);
```

Or...

Swap the two inner loops, so your last loop is the terms, then break out of that loop as soon as a match is found...

```
foreach ($data['konten'] as $kon) {
    foreach ($kon->find('h4') as $h4) {
        foreach ($data['terms'] as $term) {
            if (stripos($h4->plaintext, $term) !== false) {
                echo $h4->plaintext;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```